# writing a dictionary to json results an empty file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I want to write a dictionary in a json file. I do this by this code:

```
with open("my_file.json","w+") as f:
    json.dumps(my_dict,f)
```

But after writing, I see an empty json file.
Each element of `my_dict` is a word as key and its 50 length word embedding vector as value for example word `girl` and its vector:

```
'girl': [-0.1311900019645691, -0.1871200054883957, 0.43307000398635864, -0.41328999400138855, -0.29401999711990356, -0.004130200017243624, 0.26743999123573303, -0.07822400331497192, 0.5190600156784058, 0.7133600115776062, -0.3792000114917755, -0.880620002746582, 0.9063299894332886, -0.3437800109386444, -0.06771499663591385, -0.2867799997329712, -0.2138500064611435, 0.5637699961662292, 0.23059000074863434, 0.36699000000953674, 0.3780199885368347, -0.11691000312566757, 0.2890999913215637, -0.20220999419689178, -0.5123500227928162, 0.894569993019104, 0.17660999298095703, -0.1632000058889389, 0.4038200080394745, 0.1188800036907196, -1.2901999950408936, 0.02515999972820282, -0.21669000387191772, 0.9924299716949463, 0.24647000432014465, -0.12221000343561172, -0.05487800016999245, 0.2543500065803528, -0.5199699997901917, 0.28192999958992004, 0.45430999994277954, -0.5873399972915649, 0.26017001271247864, 0.42120999097824097, -0.4826599955558777, -0.1054999977350235, -0.29346001148223877, 0.38749998807907104, -0.9690999984741211, -0.44870999455451965]
```

how can I solve this? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json.dumps(my_dict,f)` must be `json.dump(my_dict,f)`. (No `s`.) `dumps` writes an object to a string, not to a file.

Answer (score 5):

```
with open("my_file.json","w+") as f:
    json.dump(my_dict,f)
```

You should use json.dump not dumps. You are writing to file, not to a string.